# I have drawn a StickFigure on Blue J with 2 variables. I need to add declaration for further instance variables

Tags: java, bluej

The StickFigure class only has two instance variables, xPos and yPos, which hold the x- and y-coordinates. I am trying to add declarations for three further instance variables head, body and leg that will reference instances of Circle, Triangle, and Rectangle. this is what I have done so far. I am not sure if it's been done correctly.

```
Head aHead = new Circle();
Body aBody = new Triangle();
Leg aLeg = new Rectangle();
```

Comment: What is a `StickFigure`, is it a class?

Comment: yes and it has 2 instance variables xPos and yPos... so the positions.

Comment: Yes, the new declarations look fine. Is there a diagram produced by the BlueJ, is it correct?

Comment: it hasnt worked. it says havent found class head class body class leg

Comment: I see, you don't have classes `Head`, `Body`, `Leg` defined. And `Circle`, `Triangle`, `Rectangle` classes don't implement any interfaces, right? If so, change to: `Circle aHead = new Circle();
Triangle aBody = new Triangle();
Rectangle aLeg = new Rectangle();`

Comment: I think it has worked but I also need to initialise Head to an instance of Circle with diameter 30 and colour Colour.PINK... to check if iys absoluteluy correct

Comment: Then add the source code of `Circle` class to the question to see the constructors.